# Does changing the order of compiling with GCC in unix delete files?

Tags: unix, gcc, command-line, compiler-construction

So I just messed up real bad.. I'm hoping someone can tell me I didn't just ruin everything I did for the last 4 weeks with this simple typo..

I kept making changes to my C program and would recompile to test the changes using this in terminal:

```
gcc -o server server.c
```

Due to programming for the past 5 hours straight for the most part.. I accidentally typed this the last time I tried compiling:

```
gcc -o server.c server
```

I got some long message and realized my mistake.. tried recompiling using the first way I listed.. And it says "no such file server.c"

I typed "ls" and sure enough.. my program isn't there.

Please tell me everything I did hasn't vanished? :((

Comment: This sort of experience should motivate you to pick up a source control system, like git: http://git-scm.com/

Comment: It's scary that you could have thought of doing a day's work (actually, even an hour or two's work) without considering backups in some shape or form — a VCS (version control system) of some sort for preference. I'd never risk it, though my similar 'Damascus Experience' was several decades ago now. I've been working on a piece of code for a fair amount of the day; 10 checkins so far, so that if I made a mistake at any point, I could recover easily.  Granted, there are ways I could kill my VCS (which happens to be `git`), but then I also have automatic backups via Mac OS X Time Machine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you told the compiler to read your executable, and write its output to your source file.  The file is gone. If you are on a Windows system, perhaps it could be undeleted with something like Norton Utilities. If not, you're probably out of luck.

Next time, consider using a Makefile to contain the compiler commands, so you can just type "make" to build your program. Other strategies include keeping the file open in a single editor session the whole time you're working, and using a source control system like git or subversion (which would let you back up to previous versions of the file, as well.)

Comment: UGH!!! My professor gave us sample code to use and told us to just use that gcc command. Is it still gone even if I wasn't working on it locally? I was connected to my school server via ssh

Comment: It sounds gone, unfortunately. I'm sorry this happened, but hopefully it helps a little to know that this happens to everyone -- *once.* After that, most people start using source control and backups.